# Minimize a program's windows after running it via .bat/.cmd

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to find a way to auto-minimize a program just after running it from a .bat file.
I'm launching a SSH session via putty, and I'd like putty to auto-minimize. I use it just for the SSH tunnel.

Here is my script :

```
@echo off
start "" "putty.exe" -load tunnelssh"
exit
```

Comment: You would be better off asking 2 separate questions. Since someone has answered the second, I suggest you [edit your post](http://superuser.com/posts/559177/edit), focusing on the second question (including renaming the Title/Subject) and putting the other questions into a new post! As it stands, it's not easy to answer in full

Answer (score 2):

[KiTTY](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/), a PuTTY fork, offers an [option to minimize to tray on startup](http://www.9bis.net/kitty/?page=Send%20to%20tray&zone=en). It can also be manually sent to tray in the title bar context menu.

It also has some other great features like a portable mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
start "" /min "putty.exe" ...
```

?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide PuTTY even more, have a look at TrayIt. It seems that the original site www.trayit.com is down, but [Heise](http://www.heise.de/download/tray-it-trayit-1131803.html) still has it.

You can generate rules (called profiles), depending on e.g. window title or class. If triggered, those windows can get minimized to system tray.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the proxy settings in Firefox a while back. Though I'm not exactly sure what the cause of the problem is, I was able to work around it by using the "Foxy Proxy" extension.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's solve a part of my question :)
Thanks, Michael.